# LINQ to XML. How to get some string?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<books>
  <book>
    <author>Ray</author>
    <album>Other</album>
    <cover size="large">LargeCover</cover>
    <cover size="mini">MiniCover</cover>
  </book>
</books>
```

How to get string "MiniCover"?

I wrote the code, but it does not work — string is empty;

```
 string testLink = (@"Text.xml");

            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(testLink);
            string cv = String.Empty;

            var c = from cover in xml.Elements("book")
                    where (string)cover.Attribute("size").Value == "mini"
                    select cover.Value;
            foreach (var item in c)
            {
                cv += item.ToString();
            }

            MessageBox.Show(cv);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xpath can simplify your code

```
var covers = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//cover[@size='mini']").ToList();
```

to get the inner text

```
var covers = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//cover[@size='mini']")
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: For strictness you may want to add `//book/cover...` to avoid getting any `<magazine><cover size="mini" >MiniMag</cover></magazine>`

Answer (score 1):

When using `Elements()` you have to specify the structure more precisely.

In your code, `cover` is a `<book>` element. But `size` is an attribute of `<cover>`.

```
    var c = from cover in xml.Elements("book")
                where (string)cover.Attribute("size").Value == "mini"
                select cover.Value;
```

This ought to work:

```
    var c = from cover in xml.Elements("book")
                    .Elements("cover")
                where (string)cover.Attribute("size").Value == "mini"
                select cover.Value;
```