# How to get element value by using attributes in Linq to xml?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ to XML. How to get some string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413670/linq-to-xml-how-to-get-some-string)

My XML Response look like this.

```
 <Items>
   <Item>
     <ImageSets>
       <ImageSet Category="Primary">
          <SwatchImage>
             <URL>http://xxx.com/img1.jpg</URL>
             <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
           </SwatchImage>
           </ImageSet>

          <ImageSet Category="Variant">
           <SwatchImage>
             <URL>http://xxx.com/img2.jpg</URL>
             <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
           </SwatchImage>
           </ImageSet>

          <ImageSet Category="Variant">
           <SwatchImage>
             <URL>http://xxx.com/img3.jpg</URL>
             <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
           </SwatchImage>
          </ImageSet>

          </ImageSets>
          </Item>
          </Items>
```

Now,How can i get the values (URL) of SwatchImage element, If the category name is "Variant" ? Let me know if you need more
  information.

Comment: @Reinder. Thanks for that link., I tried that logic before post here. But My XML response is somewhat  tricky.,

Comment: @Kaf ., Ok i will surely improve.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting just the URL values for specific `<ImageSet>` nodes should be fairly simple, using the code samples supplied in the link I mentioned above:

```cs
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

string[] urls = xdoc
   .XPathSelectElements("//ImageSet[@Category='Variant']/SwatchImage/URL")
   .Select(n => n.Value)
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: You dont need the StringReader and the File.ReadAllText to Load a xml-document with XDocument. You can also write XDocument.Load("file.xml")

Comment: @Tomtom you're so right... i've updated my code (was a leftover from other stuff that I tried)

Comment: @Reinder., Thanks for the replay., But I am about to get the URL of Category="Variant".., Please look at the xml response and the question i asked.,

Comment: then you only have to change the xPath expression to include the check for the Category attribute. I've updated my answer